# Best way to join vertical table and horizontal table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

What is the best way to join a horizontal and vertical table in SQL? (i.e. in this case, join ItemID of both table)

I have a table that is like this:

[image]

And Another table that is like this:

[image: Table 2]

Ideally I would like to arrange them into something like this:

**OrderID ItemID  ClientID  Description Quantity Price**

What would be the neatest simplest way to join these two different type table based on OrderID?

Right now I am converting the Item Table from vertical to horizontal first, and then joining the 2 tables. But that becomes a lot of lines of code. Just wondering if there is any simpler way. Thanks!

Comment: Just do a join to your item table 3 times using `element='description'` for instance, in your ON clause.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple inner join on vertical table

```
 select a.OrderID, a.ItemID, a.ClientID, b.Description c.Quantity d.Price
 from table2 as a
 inner join table1 as b on a.itemID = b.itemID and b.element = 'Description'
 inner join table1 as c on a.itemID = c.itemID and c.element = 'Quantity'
 inner join table1 as d on a.itemID = d.itemID and d.element = 'Price'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot in Sql server. Please refer below code snippet.

SELECT 
OrderID,ItemID,ClientID,
[Description],Quantity,Price
FROM 
(
  SELECT OrderID,i.ItemID,ClientID,i.element,i.details
  FROM Item i
  INNER JOIN Orders a
    ON i.itemid = a.itemid
) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(details)
  FOR element in ([Description],Quantity,Price)
) piv